# C++ program that sums the numbers between two integers

Tags: c++

Here is my code, it works when x < y. But not when x > y. How can I fix this? I know the problem is within the while loop and I have tried many different things but cannot solve the issue.

```
int main()
{
    int x,y;

    int total = 0;
    cout<<"Please give me an integer: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout<<"Please give me another integer: ";
    cin >> y;

    int counter = x;
    while(counter <= y ){

        total += counter;
        ++counter;    
    }

    cout << "The total of the numbers " << total<<endl;      
}
```

Comment: Um... `if (x < y) std::swap(x,y);`

Comment: where do I put that code?

Comment: Before the point in the code that you first need the values  reordered but after you read in the values.

Comment: Like this? int counter = x;
    if (x > y) std::swap(x,y);
    while(counter <= y ){
        
        
        total += counter;
        ++counter;
        
    }

Comment: Go through the logic on pen and paper with values where X > Y, X < Y and X == Y. Make a grid and write down the values of X and Y before, at each step, and after. If they make sense, then you are correct. If they do not make sense, you need to rethink, and the grid should help you decide where the new code needs to go.

Comment: Consider accepting and up voting helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another example using the STL:

```
int size = std::abs(x - y) + 1;
std::vector<int> v(size);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), std::min(x, y));
int total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Comment: thanks @ Hakon Haegland, how profieccient are you with javaFX and GUI interfaces?

Comment: Hi Dan.I think I have poor knowledge I guess, but maybe I could try learn something new. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just wondering if you had any knowledge, no problem if you dont, I found another great mentor @c0der, who seems like he has a pretty good handle with javaFX GUI. But im also taking a c++ class atm so any questions Ill be sure to ask. You have facebook?

Answer (score 5):

Unless the exercise is about writing loops, you can replace the loop with this simple formula:

```
total = (std::abs(x - y) + 1) * (x + y) / 2;
```

It's basic [arithmetic progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) math.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reverse the roles of `x` and `y` if `x > y`.

One way is to just add a check for if `x > y` and swap the logic if they are:

```
if(x < y) {
    int counter = x;
    while(counter <= y ){
        //...
    }
} else if(x > y) {
    // roles of x and y are swaped
    int counter = y;
    while(counter <= x ){
        //...
    }
} else { // optional
    // x = y
    // so however you want to handle that, you would do so here
}
```

Or, alternatively (as mentioned in comments), you could simply use [`std::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) to reverse the roles of `x` and `y` if `x > y`.

```
if(x > y) {
    std::swap(x,y);
}
int counter = x;
//...
```